# How to use let from another component in the main React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frameworks

I am react beginner and I would like to use my formIsValid let from component in the main App.js. So when it is false DeliveryNote component should be visible, but when it changes to true it hides and shows LoadProducts component

The problem is I can't transfer states to another component I know you can use redux or context for it, but I am not pretty sure how

```
  const deliveryNoteInputRef = useRef();

  const formSubmissionHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const enteredDeliveryNote = deliveryNoteInputRef.current.value;

    const enteredDeliveryNoteisValid = enteredDeliveryNote.trim() === "1234";

    let formIsValid = false;

    if (enteredDeliveryNoteisValid) {
      formIsValid = true;
      console.log(formIsValid);
    }

    if (!enteredDeliveryNoteisValid) {
      console.log(formIsValid);
      return;
    }
    console.log(enteredDeliveryNote);
  };
  return (
    <Card className="login">
      <form onSubmit={formSubmissionHandler}>
        <div className="control">
          <label htmlFor="delivery_note">Load ID</label>
          <input type="text" id="delivery_note" ref={deliveryNoteInputRef} />
        </div>
        <div className="actions">
          <button className="button">Potvrdit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: If you want to reuse the validation for different forms, you can move the logic in an function that will be called by different component (e.g. function(elementRef) { //... validation logic }); if instead you simply want the value of `formIsValid` to be accessible from different component, you can move it into the state of the older common ancestor and pass it down via props to all the relevant descendants. A third way would be using a centralized state container such as Redux and read the value from it, but implementing it for a single variable would be an "overkill".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could store the formIsValid in a localStorage or an useContext state hook and get it from there? In both ways you should be able to get the value in the parent components (and your Main App).

Here's some info about using it in a useContext hook:
[Manage state with useContext](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-manage-user-login-react-context)